# Why and how $n(\{∅\})=1$ ? (number of elements $n(\cdot)$ of a set)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

If $n(A)=1$, then it is a Singleton set. Also $n(∅)=0$ and $n(\{∅\})=1$.

What is the meaning of $n(\{∅\})=1$? Why and how $n(\{∅\})=1$ equal to 1?

Please somebody answer.

Comment: It’s the set which contains the empty set as it’s one element.

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ is the set containing the empty set and nothing else.  So it has one element, namely the empty set

Comment: Thank u guys @ Tavish and Henry. Doubt got cleared

Comment: @311411: Your edit changed the meaning of the question completely. There's a big difference between $\emptyset$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$.

Comment: quite right, I will repair it.    @HansLundmark

Comment: okay, I think we are back to the original intent of Saravanan.

Answer (score 0):

$\{\emptyset\}$(not $\emptyset$) has only one element $\emptyset$.

So it is so trivial that $n(\{\emptyset\})=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\{\emptyset\}\neq \emptyset$ since $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$, that is, $\{\emptyset \}$ has one element (the empty set). Thus $n(\{\emptyset\})=1$.